# c# months and years between given dates

Tags: c#, datetime

I try to popup a msgbox that shows the months and years of the given dates for example 
my input is:

7/2012 and 2/2013

and the output should be:

7/2012,8/2012,9/2012,10/2012,11/2012,12/2012,1/2013,2/2013

I wrote:

```csharp
    string datePart1;
    string datePart2;
    string[] date1 = new string[] { "" };
    string[] date2 = new string[] { "" };

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2013, 2, 1);  // i will be having the date time as a variable from a textbox
        DateTime begDate = new DateTime(2012, 7, 1);  // i will be having the date time as a variable from a text box

        int year, month;

        if (endDate.Month - begDate.Month < 0)
        {
            month = (endDate.Month - begDate.Month) + 12;
            endDate = new DateTime(endDate.Year - 1, endDate.Month, endDate.Day);
        }
        else
            month = endDate.Month - begDate.Month;

        year = endDate.Year - begDate.Year;
```

The above code calculates the time difference, but my attempts at outputting haven't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sample to get you started.

It provides a handy MonthsInRange() method which returns a sequence of all the months in the specified range. You can then format the returned dates using "M\\/yyyy" (see below) to output the required format. (Note: That's not a letter V, it's a backslash followed by a forward slash!)

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for an explanation of the format string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2013, 2, 1);
            DateTime begDate = new DateTime(2012, 7, 1);

            foreach (DateTime date in MonthsInRange(begDate, endDate))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("M\\/yyyy"));
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<DateTime> MonthsInRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            for (DateTime date = start; date <= end; date = date.AddMonths(1))
            {
                yield return date;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why "M\\/yyyy" and not just "M/yyyy"?

This is because the "/" character in a DateTime format string will be interpreted as the "date separator", not a literal "/". In some locales, this will come out as "." and not "/".

To fix this, we need to escape it with a "\" character. However, we can't just use a single "\" because C# itself will interpret that as an escape character, and will use it to escape the following character. The C# escape sequence for a literal "\" is "\\", which is why we have to put "\\/" and not just "\/".

Alternatively you can turn of escaping of "\" characters by prefixing the string with an @ character, like so:

```
@"M/yyyy"
```

You can use whichever you prefer.

Comment: but when even though it writes date.ToString("M/yyyy") it outputs 7.2012 for example. not 7/2012.  when i write different thing rather then / it separates according to that separator but with / separator it outputs . just like . separator. why? you have any idea

Comment: Yes, it's because the "/" character is not interpreted literally - instead it's converted to the "date separator" character, which is locale-dependent. I'll update my answer to solve this issue.

Comment: thanks great explanation hope it will be a nice article for the people who looks for an answer about that issue also. by the way i will chose an answer and above i think Austin's solution works also even though i couldn't make it run because I'm a newbie but i trace the code it need to give the correct output. which answer i need to chose and why? your answer looks shorter and seems eligate but to be honest i didn't understand much about the "public static IEnumerable<DateTime> MonthsInRangei......" and "yield return..." parts.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not guaranteed to have dates with the same day, you can use this code which creates new dates that only consider the first of the month.

```
static IEnumerable<string> InclusiveMonths(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    // copies to ensure the same day.
    var startMonth = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, 1);
    var endMonth = new DateTime(end.Year, end.Month, 1);

    for (var current = startMonth; current <= endMonth; current = current.AddMonths(1))
        yield return current.ToString("M/yyyy");
}

// usage
foreach (var mmyyyy in InclusiveMonths(begDate, endDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine(mmyyyy);
}

var allMonths = string.Join(", ", InclusiveMonths(begDate, endDate));
```

Comment: no Austin i will be taking the date information from a textbox so dates will be changing

Comment: Austin it should work but i couldn't manage it. i use winform and i will show the msg when button1 is clicked. by the way if i have to chose an answer which answer i should chose Matthews or yours. Matthews worked fine and your answer should also work fine but i couldn't make it run.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the TimeSpan structure, it'll help you achieve your goal a lot faster.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
TimeSpan dateDifference = endDate - begDate;
year = dateDifference.Days / 365;
month = dateDifference.Days / 30;
```

**Edit:**
I forgot `TimeSpan` does not feature `Year` or `Month`, sorry :(